# UIScrollView in UITableView content problems

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview inside each cell in my tableview, although the pictures embed in my scrollview don't show up until i scroll the tableview up and down...
I have a custom class with a @property for the scrollview and the cell. I have my code for setting the scrollview in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. This should be called upon initial creation of the cells as well? Im confused.

How can I get rid of the problem and make the images appear at first when I start the app?

Related code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"CustomID";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < [imageArray count]; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = cell.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = cell.scrollView.frame.size;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        [cell.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    }

    cell.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(cell.scrollView.frame.size.width * [imageArray count], cell.scrollView.frame.size.height);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: Where do you instanciate the scroll view? Did you design the `CustomCell`in IB/Storyboard Editor?

Comment: What is the default size of the cell and the scroll view - is the frame equal to `CGRectZero`?

Comment: That depends on where you created it and how. If you don't set any frame than it is CGRectZero. But that is unlikely. So where and how are they created? IB? Programmatically in the cell's init/initWithStyle: method?

Comment: you should add imageView as property in CustomCell. Alloc it in initWithStyle. And then you will to add images only in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Yes, in Interface Builder for my storyboard. Ok thx stosha I will try this

Comment: I cant get it to work, how would i best instantiate the scrollview and add the subviews?

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly related to your question but you will run into this issue too:

Don't forget that your cells will be reused. Upon reusage (lets say the user scrolls down, a cell is moved upwards off the screen and the next that appears on the bottom will be physically the instance of CustomCell that just disappeard and was reused.)

Therefore add:

```
   for (UIView *aView in [NSArray arrayWithArray:cell.subviews]) {
       [aView removeFromSuperview];
       // if you don't arc then release them and take care of their subviews - if any. 
   }
```

before adding any new UIImageView. 
(I thought there was a method for removing all subviews in one go but did not find it)

Comment: In this case, I think he should be remove subviews from the `cell.scrollView.subviews`. Just be careful, that if you remove all subviews from a UIScrollView, the scrolling indicators will also be removed. You need to do some sort of check (based on tag, or on the class) so you can remove only your content from the scrollview.